# My asp.net code do not work on iis7.5 but works perfectly on iis6.0

Tags: iis-6

Error while browsing. Im using Windows 7 and IIS 7.5

Expected ')' Line 245, Char 43

I checked the codes and there is no error. Im using asp.net(VB.net)

Error on Line 245, the problem is my code is only having 150 lines. No 245 line.

I installed this to iis6.0 and it works perfectly. dont know what is the difference of iis6 and ii7.7

Hope someone could help me.. Thanks!